# Can we prove elliptic regularity by reducing to a first order system of PDE?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, regularity-theory-of-pdes, elliptic-equations

Theorem 10.3.6 of Nicolaescu's [notes](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://www3.nd.edu/%7Elnicolae/Lectures.pdf&ved=2ahUKEwimjKG8je_-AhWFD1kFHbOGAvAQFnoECAgQAQ&usg=AOvVaw0hZAaEOGOFyp2_rVk_m09q) prove elliptic regularity for a first order PDO. I noted that this PDO is allowed to be interpreted as a system of first order pde's. Now, given any linear, elliptic PDO, we can replace each derivative with a new variable and adjoin all definitions into a single system of equations that gives rise to a first order PDO. Unless ellipticity is destroyed by this order reduction, I don't see why we could not prove elliptic regularity in general from the special case proved in the theorem.

I fail to see why reducing the order of a PDE would destroy its ellipticity, is there something I am missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it would help to see an example to see why this fails. You are correct that an elliptic PDE like $-\Delta u = f$ can be reduced to first order by setting $\vec v = \nabla u$ to yield the system
$$ \begin{cases} \nabla u = \vec v \\ -\nabla\cdot \vec v = f \end{cases} $$
which writing $\vec w := \binom{u}{\vec v}, A := \left(\begin{matrix} \nabla & 0 \\ 0 & -\nabla\cdot\end{matrix}\right), \vec F(\vec w) := \binom{\vec v}{f}$ can be written more abstractly as $A\vec w = \vec F(\vec w)$.

Now your question seems to imply that there is some first-order PDO that is equivalent to $-\Delta$ in terms of its properties. The problem is that in reducing the equation, you have also changed the right-hand side since it also depends on the original input variable. So neither of the possible first order operators here, $A$ and $A - F$ play the correct role (the first does not include all the relevant information about the $\vec w$ that solves the Laplace equation and $A - F$ includes the arbitrary function $f$ as a parameter). So just because you can reduce a partial differential equation does NOT mean you can 'reduce' a partial differential operator to first order.